# Eigenvalue decomposition of a certain symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The matrix in question is:

> $$
> A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 2N-1 & N-1 & 0 & & &\cdots & 0  \\
> N-1 & 2N-3 & N-2 & 0 & & \cdots & 0 \\
> 0 & N-2 & 2N-5 & \ddots & & & \vdots \\
> \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
> & & & \ddots & \ddots & 2 & 0\\
> \vdots& & & & 2 & 3 & 1\\
> 0& \cdots & & & 0 & 1 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

What I'm looking for is $U\sqrt{\Sigma}$ and $\sqrt{\Sigma}^{-1}U^T$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, $\Sigma$ is a tridiagonal matrix given by:

> $$
> U\Sigma^2U^T = A
> $$

I'm using MATLAB to solve the eigenvalue decomposition. However, the precision is not good enough. Is it possible to exploit the structure of this given matrix to get better accuracy?

Comment: Have you tried using a rootfinding method for its recurrence relation? See, for example, this [reference](http://math.oregonstate.edu/~restrepo/475A/Notes/sourcea-/node59.html) for computing the roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$
f_k(\lambda) = (\alpha_k-\lambda)f_{k-1}(\lambda) - \beta^2_{k-1}f_{k-2}(\lambda)
$$
where $\alpha_k$ is the $k^{th}$ element of the main diagonal and $\beta_k$ is the $k^{th}$ element of the off diagonal. Not sure, but maybe worth a try

Comment: Thank you. Nope, I have not tried that method. Honestly I dont really understand how to use it.